# Looping through different sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I would appreciate your help with the macro I am trying to create.

I have an xls file with a bunch of worksheets, some of which named "1", "2", "3", and so forth. I would like to create a macro that loops only through those 'number-named' worksheets, hence NOT according to the index as in the code below. (Sheet "1" is not the first sheet in the workbook). Before the loop I need to define both the cell range and sheets.

Below is my (wrong) attempt.

```
Sub Refresh ()

Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A10:TZ180")

 For i = 1 To 30

  Sheets(i).Activate
  rng.Select       
  rng.ClearContents
  Application.Run macro:="xxx"

 Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: Your `rng` variable is not used correctly. After you assign the range it doesn't change just because you activate a different sheet.

Comment: Trying to use `rng.select` after activating a different sheet will give the error: "Select method of Range class failed". This is because you cannot select a range on a non active sheet. So you need to assign the range to each different sheet before using like that. Your `Set rng = Range("A10:TZ180")` must be after `Sheets(i).Activate` and then it will set the range to the active sheet.

Answer (score 5):

```
dim w as worksheet
for each w in activeworkbook.worksheets
  if isnumeric(w.name) then
    w.range("A10:TZ180").clearcontents
    xxx()
  end if
next
```

Comment: This definitely does the trick. I had a similar solution but didn't think to use isNumeric - nice.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.  
That doesn't seem to be working though.  The application (last line within the loop) runs over the specified range. I tried to edit the code but it is still not working. Also, I would like to define both the range and sheets before the loop.

Comment: @korone You can't define the range before the loop because you want to operate on the range within each sheet. So each sheet has a different range although having the same address.

Comment: @D_Bester All of the 'number-named' sheets are symmetric to one other and have the same range. Shouldn't it be possible to define the range before the loop then?

Comment: @korone They have the same address only if you ignore the sheet name. They are not the same range. So you cannot assign a range variable until you have the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If the macro "xxx()" requires a selected range you just need to add a select statement. (Borrowing from GSerg)

```
Dim w As Worksheet
For Each w In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  If IsNumeric(w.Name) Then
    w.Range("A10:TZ180").ClearContents
    w.Range("A10:TZ180").Select
    Application.Run macro:="xxx"
  End If
Next
```

To clear up your misunderstanding about assigning a range see the following:

```
Sub Refresh()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If IsNumeric(ws.Name) Then

            'you must activate the worksheet before selecting a range on it
            ws.Activate

            'note the qualifier: ws.range()
            Set rng = ws.Range("A10:TZ180")

            'since the range is on the active sheet, we can select it
            rng.Select
            rng.ClearContents
            Application.Run macro:="xxx"
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Sub test2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rg As Range

    Dim arrSheets As Variant
    arrSheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")

    Dim x As Long
    For x = LBound(arrSheets) To UBound(arrSheets)
        Set ws = Worksheets(arrSheets(x))
        ws.Activate

        '...

    Next
End Sub

Sub test3()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To 20
        Set ws = Worksheets(CStr(x))
        ws.Activate

        '...

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, the code works! However, as I said I would like to pre-define the list of 'number-named' sheets over which I want to run the loop (say from 1 to 20 for example). As the code is now, the loop would run over all the 'number-named' sheets.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Sub main()
Dim shtNames As Variant, shtName As Variant

shtNames = Array(1, 2, 3, 4) '<== put your actual sheets "number name"

For Each shtName In shtNames
    With Worksheets(CStr(shtName))
        .Range("A10:TZ180").ClearContents
        .Range("A10:TZ180").Select
        Application.Run macro:="MacroToRun"
    End With
Next shtName

End Sub


Sub MacroToRun()

MsgBox "hello from cells '" & Selection.Address & "' in sheet '" & ActiveCell.Parent.Name & "'"
End Sub
```